# Is there an instructive image where I can see a spectrum and a spectrogram, side-by-side?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, praat

I’m sometimes confused about representations of speech sounds.

Even if I know a spectrum is 2D and a spectrogram is 3D, and the axes are different, I often struggle to figure our what I’m looking at.

It’d be great to find a couple images e.g. of CV  syllables or even just phonemes as a  spectrum and spectrogram, to better understand in my own mind how they are different and could be “read”.

Maybe some of you guys know of some good pointers or instructive examples.